# wxBufferedPaintDC GetGraphicsContext return NULL pointer

Tags: wxwidgets

To get rid of flicker, I use wxBufferedPaintDC in place of wxPaintDC. But there comes a problem. In my paint function, in order to draw a cubic beizer curve I must use GetGraphicsContext to create a path. My question is why GetGraphicsContext returns a NULL pointer when using wxBufferedPaintDC.

```
void DotGraphView::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent & WXUNUSED(evt))
{
    wxBufferedPaintDC dc(this);

    PrepareDC(dc);

    PaintBackground(dc);

    wxGCDC &gdc = (wxGCDC&)dc;
    wxGraphicsContext * gc = gdc.GetGraphicsContext(); /* here gc = NULL */
    wxGraphicsPath path = gc->CreatePath(); /* program collapses here */

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cast that you have from `wxBufferedPaintDC` to `wxGCDC` looks a little suspicious to me, the [wxGraphicsContext](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_graphics_context.html)  pages suggests doing it like this:

```
wxGraphicsContext *gc = wxGraphicsContext::Create( dc );
if (gc)
{
    //drawing code here
    delete gc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel suspicious too, the suggestion page does not work.
Now I use the following codes and the program run ok.

```
wxBufferedPaintDC pdc(this);

wxGCDC gdc;
wxGraphicsRenderer * const renderer = wxGraphicsRenderer::GetDefaultRenderer();
wxGraphicsContext * context = renderer->CreateContext(pdc);
gdc.SetGraphicsContext(context);

wxDC & dc = (wxDC &)gdc;
PrepareDC(dc);

Draw(dc);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use wxAutoBufferedPaintDC.
There is no need to buffer on some platform (like GTK).

Then, you can use the constructor

```
wxGCDC gcdc(dc);
```

This works at least on GTK and MSW.